# Blender and Unreal Engine 4

Tags: animation, rigging, export, unreal-engine

What is the current progress on making Blender and the Unreal Engine 4 more compatible? Importing static meshes from Blender works satisfactory in most cases but rigs and animations are difficult due to scale and other issues.

In my dream scenario I would like to have a UE4 button in the Blender interface that would configure everything for maximum compatibility with UE4. Why not even start up with the UE4 mannequin? Perhaps even rigged? Maybe that is asking too much but at least have scale, import-export options, orientation, materials and other settings preset to UE4, and have animation export work properly.

I don't suppose any of this could be achieved in a not to distant release of Blender? I love to model my assets in Blender but I am frustrated just like many others over the compatibility issues, especially in regards to animations.

Does anyone have some answers to this? Anyone knows of a good *working* workflow between Blender and UE4 for animations and rigs?

Is there any dedicated website for Blender and UE4 workflow?